# Android apps not working with HTTP proxy

Tags: applications, networking, proxy, troubleshooting

So I want to redirect my Android phone's HTTP traffic through a proxy running on my computer, in my case Burp Suite.

I tried doing so by changing the WiFi settings and also by using the Drony app. I also installed Burp's SSL certificate on my phone.

When I visit websites using Chrome, everything works fine both on HTTP and on HTTPS, and I can see all the requests on Burp. But when I use a different app - any app - I get a "cannot connect to the Internet" error message and I can't use the app.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

I should also mention that my phone is not rooted.

Comment: I found the answer here. https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/android-proxyhandler-battery-optimization.html After following the instructions, my proxy worked correctly, for the Play Store, and several other apps. Power Optimization is not allowing the proxy handlers to work correctly.

Comment: My answer to similar question about Fiddler: [Why is not all traffic captured from my device when routing through proxy?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/219280/218526)

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you are trying to use apps over HTTP proxy which causes many apps to show connectivity error.
Try a VPN over proxy.
Connect as usual you connect to the internet through your HTTP proxy. AS chrome supports proxy, the internet works fine in it even with a proxy.
Then Search for Surfeasy VPN. 
I have tried many VPN's and only this and OpenVPN got success in establishing a connection with HTTP proxy. 
Try this, it works great.
 It even bypasses the restrictions over proxy if set up by Colleges, schools, Cafes.

Comment: Alright, downloaded Surfeasy. How exactly do I use it with an HTTP proxy? Could you elaborate? Thanks.

Comment: It's a VPN mate. just connect with it.